# Actionmailer instance variable problem Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have an email scheduler setup to send a daily e-mail with updates about the site to all users,

However, when I try and send the e-mail, all variables come back as nil, i'm assuming because nothing is explicitly defined. i.e. No one is submitting a form with their email, clicking submit and triggering an e-mail, it's just a daily email to all users, that for simplicities sake, we'll say should contain the receiving user's email address.

```
     <%= @user.email %>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
    def newideas_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user, :subject => "Here are the latest ideas from your team")
    end
```

and here's the scheduler task:

```
    scheduler.every("30m") do  
    Account.all.each do |account|
    account.users.each do |user|
    Newideas.newideas_email(user.email).deliver
    end
    end
    end
```

and here's the actual e-mail code:

```
    <% @user.account.ideas.each do |idea| %>  
    <li><%= idea.title %></li> 
    <% end %>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using for the mailer?

Comment: Can you post the code in from your mailer object (the one that derives from ActionMailer::Base)?  Also, the line of code that calls my_mailer.deliver_xxx().  It's hard to figure out what's going on lacking this code..

Comment: I edited the above to include all of the related code. Thanks

Comment: Rails 3. Does some of the above look like rails 2?

Answer (score 3):

In your scheduled code, you're passing through the user's email address to the mailer `Newideas.newideas_email(user.email)`. What you probably meant to do was pass the user object itself `Newideas.newideas_email(user)`, because your view template is expecting it to be an `ActiveRecord`.